# What is the best tool to make a CD-ROM Demo Application?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, desktop-application

I have to make an application that will do the following:

- Open a video file embedded in the application
- Open some pdf files, preferably embedded in the application, but if it will have to open externally, it's no problem.
- Work in fullscreen on the user computer, with a minimum resolution of 1024x768. I'm thinking about a resolution of 1024x768, centered on a black background.

I was thinking of using Flash, but I don't have much experience, so if there is another easier IDE that creates a Flash application, I would prefer that.
So, if anyone knows any Flash component to do this, I'll be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a Flash CDROM takes a little bit of care, but from my experience it's well worth it. From your requirements, the Flash IDE is well up to the task. The common requirements are as follows:

- Windows / Mac platform
- Flash Projector file
- Autorun file (For the Windows platform)
- Net access or all local

If your client is happy with creating the CDROM just for Windows, there will be very few dramas - but if they want to create a Mac-friendly version, you can do that too and I will explain afterwards.

Your Flash should preferably be an .exe projector file - the reason for this is so that the Windows user can open your app without downloading a Flash player (If the client wants a CDROM, they probably have limited net access, so this is a good thing!)

Within Flash, you can perform all your standard fs commands including full-screen.

You will likely need an Autorun file so that the user sees your application as soon as you put in the CDROM - simply create a file named 'autorun.inf' in notepad and enter the following:

[autorun]
open=yourProjector.exe

Where 'yourProjector.exe' is the name and path of your projector file.

It sounds like you're going to embed your videos and content in the CDROM - this is usually the ideal case, since your client won't receive annoying security messages, but this can also be a bad thing if you want to correct your content later (spotting errors after a thousand CDROMS have been distributed can be a PAIN).
You can serve some of your content online to avoid this, but it would give your user some ugly messages, so as long as you triple-check your content and embed everything, it would be the best scenario.

Now for a Mac, Apple has done away with autorun features years ago - there is a way to turn it on through Quicktime, but this is off by default for almost all Mac users, and turning it on is not recommended because it makes the Mac vulnerable to the 'Hong Kong Virus', one of the few Mac viruses around.

You can make your CDROM mac-friendly by creating a Mac Projector and adding instructions for how to use it by changing the background image of the CDROM window. I haven't had to do it before, but I hear that it's not too difficult.

Comment: Thank you. It will run only in windows PC machines. Your reply was very helpful.
I heard about a flash paper and they advise me to use it instead of the PDF. I still did not convert the MS Word files to PDF, so could be a flash paper as well.
Anyone here has ever use it to do a task like this?

Comment: it seems like what you have is MS Word files - if you present them in the projector, I would personally re-represent the data in Flash. I haven't used Flash paper, but if your main goal is to display the content, then it doesn't matter how you do it :p
So really, if you want the user to download your documents, then zip them up and link to it via relative path. If you want them to be able to read the content from the fullscreen program, just re-represent the data with movieclips/textfields or whatever you feel like :)

Comment: Thank you Garrt. But it really seams not possible, because is sort of 200 documents of 50 pages each. So if there is the possibility of the flash paper or another pdf player embedded in the projector, it wold facilitate my work.

Comment: I would suggest organising the documents in Acrobat, and letting the user download it from a link in your app. The Projector approach is only useful for:
- making an autorun file to guide the user
- creating a rich user experience

Neither of these are going to make it easy to view your documents, so you may need to find a method to create PDF's from your Word files.
FlashPaper is not developed anymore, your solution is to print using Adobe's virtual printer instead to create PDF's. This would not be directly viewable in Flash.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Flash Projector. Here is a [tutorial](http://www.tutorialized.com/view/tutorial/Produce-Flash-Projector-Files/27034) to get you started. Now, you won't be able to embed the PDF files but you can open them easily enough using [fscommand](http://www.adobe.com/support/flash/action_scripts/actionscript_dictionary/actionscript_dictionary372.html)("exec","foo.pdf")

Comment: 'easy' is a bit optimistic, fscommand has a lot of limitations in as3.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Adobe AIR Application; however it won't run off the CD ROM; it'll need to be installed locally.

If creating a projector from Flash Pro doesn't work; look at a tool like [Janus](http://www.janus-flash.com/) or [Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/)